# Где на хостинге httpd.conf?

Tags: ssh, apache2, config

Есть сайт на хостинге, связка apache2 + nginx. Требуется включить директиву mod_headers для настройки кеширования. Но где мне найти этот файл конфигурации? Подключился по SSH, выполнил команду `locate httpd.conf` - консоль ничего не выдает. Пробовал команду `find -name httpd.conf` - тот же результат.
Хостинг FASTVPS.

Comment: Если услуга хостинг, а не на vps, то эти настройки только через панель

Comment: а ищешь ты где с помощью find, кто будет указывать путь поиска ?

find / -name httpd.conf
,поставь / , от корня
а так он ищет в текущем каталоге.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не обязательно будет файл ***httpd.conf*** 
В зависимости от ОС + Настроек хостера

```
cd /etc/httpd/
```

Или как пример

```
cd /etc/apache2/
```

Дальше ищите файлы которые относятся к конфигам. Может быть будет папки по типу "***mods-available***"

Для nginx может быть /etc/nginx/

Тут только смотреть